# export vue.js graphs to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html2canvas

I am trying to export a dashboard built with vue.js to a pdf file.

tried using `html2canvas`, but when trying to export the rendered image, some graphs are being cut halfway on a new page.

looking for an alternative that will render the graphs as a whole "block", or even export each graph to a new page in the pdf.

what would be the best approach for this?